# Monthly payments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say you buy a piece of furniture for $120 and you are going to make payments for the next 12 months on it with no interest. I am trying to make a program where it tells you the payment each month for the next 12 months. The program I made tells you the monthly payment/amount due for the first month but it just copies the first month for all 12 months and I was wondering if someone can lead me in the right direction so the amount due is correct for all 12 months. I know I am messing some kind of equation but can't come up with it. I am still very new at python and having some trouble. Here is what I made:

```
purchasePrice = input("Enter purchase price")
purchasePrice = int(purchasePrice)
month = 1
 while month <=12:
  print (month)
  month = month + 1
  monthlyPayment = purchasePrice/12
  amountDue = purchasePrice - monthlyPayment 
  print ("Monthly payment", monthlyPayment)
  print ("Amount due: ", amountDue)
```

and my output is:

```
Enter purchase price 120
1
Monthly payment 10.0
Amount due:  110.0
2
Monthly payment 10.0
Amount due:  110.0
3
Monthly payment 10.0
Amount due:  110.0
4
Monthly payment 10.0
Amount due:  110.0
```

and that goes on till month 12

Comment: Change `amountDue = purchasePrice - monthlyPayment` to `amountDue = purchasePrice - (monthlyPayment * month)`

Comment: monthlyPayment is declared inside the loop. This means each time you overwrite the valuse with the initial value. Move the declaration up above the loop start.

Comment: @Tera I noticed a few other things that can be cleaned up some and will hlp you out some. I posted it as an answer breaking down how to condense and clean up your code some.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that every time while this line runes
amountDue = purchasePrice - monthlyPayment 
purchasePrice = 120 and monthlyPayment = 10 so amountDue doesnt change.
You need to multiply months to monthlyPayment to see how many times you have paid monthlyPayment. And change the sequence of lines because month is already equals to 1. So your code will look like

```
purchasePrice = input("Enter purchase price")
purchasePrice = int(purchasePrice)
month = 1
while month <=12:
  print (month)
  monthlyPayment = purchasePrice/12
  amountDue = purchasePrice - monthlyPayment * month
  month = month + 1
  print ("Monthly payment", monthlyPayment)
  print ("Amount due: ", amountDue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple variables that are declared inside of the loop. When you declare a variable inside of a loop it is destroyed and overwritten each iteration of the loop. You want to declare variables OUTSIDE of the loop to preserve them for each iteration.

```
purchasePrice = input("Enter purchase price")
purchasePrice = int(purchasePrice)

#Variable declaration for preservation.
month = 1
monthlyPayment = purchasePrice/12
ammountDue = purchasePrice

while month <=12:
    print (month)
    ##This is a condensed way of doing 'month = month + 1'
    month += 1
    ##Again this is a condensed form of 'amountDue = amountDue - monthlyPayment'
    amountDue -= monthlyPayment 
    print ("Monthly payment", monthlyPayment)
    print ("Amount due: ", amountDue)
```

Now that the base form is working we can condense the code into something a little cleaner and with less code in general.

Revised Cleaner Form:

```
##Condensed two lines into one.
purchasePrice = int(input("Enter purchase price"))

#Variable declaration for preservation.
monthlyPayment = purchasePrice/12

##Changing from a while loop to a for loop lets us remove the month variable
for x in range(1, 13)
    print (x)
    print ("Monthly payment", monthlyPayment)
    ##Here we get rid of the amountDue variable and just perform the calculation in the output
    print ("Amount due: ", purchasePrice -((purchasePrice/12)*x))
```